In Moon, why does Sam ask GERTY to activate a third clone before the rescue team arrives?
In the movie, Moon (2009), I don't quite understand why Sam II (the second clone, not the original one) asks GERTY to wake up yet another clone (the third) before the ELIZA rescue team arrives or else they will kill both him and SAM I.
If I understand the movie correctly, the rescue team was expecting to find two clones anyway — one dead in the crashed rover (SAM I could have been that one, as in fact he did at the end) and one active (SAM II) — so why bring up a third one to avoid creating any suspicion in the rescue team?

Sam, being a clever guy and recognising that his opponents are unscrupulous, launches a multi-pronged attack on his present enslavement.

His younger, healthier clone will undertake a risky journey to Earth in a cargo pod. It's possible that he won't survive and that only his body will be discovered by the ground crew, but even that would still be a 'win' if it results in call to the authorities.

In the event that he does survive re-entry, the chances of him making his getaway from the landing site are much higher if the evil Lunar Industries doesn't realise that one of their clones is missing.

Sam-6 orders a new clone to be revived, to allay the suspicions of the "rescue" team (e.g. clone kill squad). When they arrive, they'll find a newly decanted Sam-7 working away like a happy little beaver.


Which brings us neatly to

Sam has programmed one of the harvesters to crash into an antenna,  allowing the Sam clone that's on the moon to have live communications with  Earth. Even if all of his other plans fail, his corpse is disposed of and no investigation takes place, this one could still work.


Conversely, If the kill squad arrive and find no live clones, they're unlikely to activate any new ones until they can identify what happened to the previous one. That makes it far more likely that the one in the Pod will be tracked down and eliminated, and it makes it less likely that there will be one on the Moon, actively working when the antenna is broken and live transmissions are reactivated.
